# Event listeners get removed after adding/removing some elements of a list

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener, htmlcollection

I have a `<ul>` list with some `<li>` elements inside, and I've added a `click` event listener for each of these elements to move the clicked item to the top of the list.

```js
function add_event_listeners() {
    let elements = my_list.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (let item of elements) {
        item.addEventListener("click", send_to_top);
    }
}

function send_to_top() {
    this.parentElement.children[0].insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', this);
}
```

This code **works fine until I remove or add** a new `li` to the list, all the event listeners get removed, and the clicks after that don't work.

What's the proper event listener to use to detect that a new element has been added or removed from the list? So I can use it to run the `add_event_listeners()` function after that?

Based on the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) documentation on MDN:

> An `HTMLCollection` in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated
> when the underlying document is changed. For this reason it is a good
> idea to make a copy (eg. using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) to iterate over if adding,
> moving, or removing nodes.

Can anyone help with a code sample of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was avoiding using the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to capture any changes in the HTML of the list because I thought it would be complicated and performance-consuming.

I was able to manage that using this code:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver( () => authors_list__add_listeners() );
observer.observe(my_list, { childList: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of future viewers of this question:

Were you using `.innerHTML +=` to add the new stuff?

At the time of this comment (November 2022), the culprit that destroys existing event listeners (even on unrelated elements) seems to be

`.innerHTML +=`

so try using a different technique.

For example, avoid:

**HTML Insertion Technique 1 (which inserts the HTML but also inadvertently seems to erase any existing event listeners on other unrelated elements, so is NOT recommended):**

`document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="something"</div>';`

Instead, use the following (or some other technique):

**Technique 2 (which works and does not affect existing event listeners):**

`document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend','<div id="something"</div>');`

...or any other way (such as with `append` and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Somehow mine works by just refactoring the code, see below:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="lists">
      <li class="list-item">
        <div>List #1</div>
        <button class="btn-send-up">Send to top</button>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div>List #2</div>
        <button class="btn-send-up">Send to top</button>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div>List #3</div>
        <button class="btn-send-up">Send to top</button>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div>List #4</div>
        <button class="btn-send-up">Send to top</button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <script>
      const listsEl = document.getElementById('lists');

      const addEventListeners = () => {
        const sendUpBtnEls = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-send-up');

        sendUpBtnEls.forEach((sendUpBtnEl) => {
          sendUpBtnEl.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const listItemEl = e.target.closest('.list-item');

            listsEl.firstElementChild.insertAdjacentElement(
              'beforebegin',
              listItemEl,
            );
          });
        });
      };

      addEventListeners();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @unspeakable29, but I forgot to mention when this issue happens. It happens when I add a new `li` to the list or remove one. I mean when the HTML of the `ul` element is updated.

Comment: @JafarAbazeed I see, if it's new `li` means you have to attach the same event to that element as well. Because the current event listeners will only be attached to those `li` that was already in the DOM at the time of execution. For new elements, you will have to attach the add event listeners to them again.